# Decode with AND clause oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use parameter in my query but I can't handle with it

I have 3 big selects to raport and I just want to use parameter for some part of code which depends from choice

I have 3 different Where conditions

1st
`..WHERE A.CANCELLED = 'FALSE' AND a.open_amount!=0 AND A.IDENTITY = '&client_id'..`

2nd

```
...WHERE A.CANCELLED = 'FALSE' AND A.IDENTITY = '&client_id' ...
```

3rd

```
WHERE AND A.CANCELLED = 'FALSE' AND a.invoice_amount != a.open_amount AND A.IDENTITY = '&client_id'
```

I tried with decode but I guess it could be ok if there would be value in 2nd case but there isn't and I cant decode like this

```
WHERE decode(xxx,x1,'AND a.open_amount!= 0',x2,'',x3, 'AND a.invoice_amount != a.open_amount')
```

How I should solve that problem any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean, if the first "where condition" OR the second OR the third is/are TRUE, you want the overall to be TRUE (select the row), and you are looking for a simplified way to write it? That is, without simply combining them with OR?

To achieve that, you don't need CASE and nested CASE statements or DECODE. You could do it like this:

```
WHERE A.CANCELLED = 'FALSE' 
  AND A.IDENTITY  = '&client_id'
  AND ( (xxx = x1 AND a.open_amount != 0) OR (xxx = x2) OR 
        (xxx = x3 AND a.invoice_amount != a.open_amount)    )
```

This is more readable, the intent is clear, it will be easier to modify if needed, ...

Comment: Yes, I overthought that a bit... *8-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like -

```
 WHERE A.CANCELLED = 'FALSE'
   AND A.IDENTITY = '&client_id'
   AND a.open_amount <>
          (CASE
              WHEN x1 THEN 0
              WHEN x2 THEN a.open_amount + 1 -- This needs to be something that is always TRUE, to nullify the condition
              WHEN x3 THEN a.invoice_amount
           END);
```

Edit: This is based on the assumption that `a.open_amount` is a `NUMBER` and uses a quick hack where we create an always `TRUE` condition like `x <> x + 1`. You should probably change this to whatever suits you better based on your data.

Comment: Will the `x2` condition work if `open_amount` is null?  It may not be nullable anyway, but I think if it is then that could give a different result to the OP's second standalone condition?

Comment: @AlexPoole You are absolutely right. Good call. I'll leave it here as is since I like mathguy's answer better. This was supposed to be a hack anyway :)